# Laravel route doesn't work. localhost8000/{route}/create always be ignored

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-7

Laravel route doesn't work.   localhost8000/{route}/create always be ignored.
the create() function of the controller doesn't seem to be called.
The browser tries to link to the same page or /home
How Should I fix and check this?

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('/debug', 'WorkerController')->except(['index'])->middleware('auth');
```

```
class WorkController extends Controller
{
    public function create(WorkRequest $request)
    {
        Log::debug("This function never be called", "!!");

        return view("a");
    }

    public function store(WorkRequest $request)
    {
        $schedules = DB::table('schedules')->get();

        $request->date;
        $request->hours;
        $worker_id = strval($request->user()->id);
        Log::debug('date=' . $request->date);
        //omit

        $registerred_schedules = DB::table('worker_schedules')->where('worker_id', $worker_id)->get();

        return view('workers.create', ['schedules' => $registerred_schedules]);
    }
}
```

```
|        | POST      | debug                         | debug.store      | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@store                    | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | debug/create                  | debug.create     | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@create                   | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE    | debug/{debug}                 | debug.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@destroy                  | web,auth   |
|        | PUT|PATCH | debug/{debug}                 | debug.update     | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@update                   | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | debug/{debug}                 | debug.show       | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@show                     | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | debug/{debug}/edit            | debug.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\WorkController@edit                     | web,auth   |
```

Comment: try name you action controller as 'store' not 'create'

Comment: did you try this route ```localhost:8000/debug/{route}/create```?

Comment: Please can you show the code for the link you're using to get to the page.

Comment: I tried  http://localhost:8000/debug/create

Comment: when I try to link /debug  then 
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: I think it's because you `->except(['index'])` excepting the index, so by default `/debug` will be the POST method, if you want to access it via link, you should remove the `except`

Comment: Umm. I modified and removed ```->except(['index']) ```  , yet nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

Route `/debug` point to `WorkController@store` and follow the POST method.
So when you access it via GET method you get an exception.

While `debug/create` point to `WorkController@create` and follow the GET method.

So `/debug/create` should load your form or view and `/debug` should store the form data.

The index method is missing from your controller otherwise it would have called as default on `/debug` and had a GET method.

Comment: 'I know that. I tried to link via POST/GET method but any functions in WorkController are not called    ''<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/debug"></form>'''

Comment: Please add your form in the question.